# After using PowerPoint my monitors are no longer recognized

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

My normal setup is a laptop + laptop monitor, and 2 external screens connected via a onelink lenovo adaptor (a small docking station).

After using my computer in a meeting room with a projector I have experienced that my 2 external screens are no longer usable.

I had PowerPoint open in the meeting room and I think I just pulled out the plug and inserted my laptop to the onelink lenovo adaptor.

Now my monitors 2+3 aren't recognized anymore. They are no longer visible in display settings, except when I run a presentation in PowerPoint. When I do that they become visible in display settings.

I suspect this may be something specific for how PowerPoint optimizes multible monitory.

I am certain I have encountered it before and did something where I didn't have to update my BIOS.

Any good ideas? I don't want to run a presentation in the background forever.

Comment: Did you just try to reboot? If that solves it, it's not much of an issue, right? BTW adding information about your video card(s) and monitors could help.

Comment: Tried pressing Window+P ?

Comment: Reboot did nothing, windows+p and extend solved it when PowerPoint wasn't running. @p._phidot_ if you want free internet points feel free to make it an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is the presentation screen mode selection shortcut for the Windows OS. It is very useful for two screen setups.

When it comes to a three screen setup, you still need to use the Control Panel screen resolution page.

Answer (score 2):

The Win+P posted by @RobinCTS is actually a solution but what needs to be done is:

1. connect all screens even if they do not display anything and are "not detectable"
2. WIN+P and select "PC screen only"
3. select "Extend"
4. screens should return to normal.

For some reasons after this issue happens the control panel and Display settings no longer recognize  other screens as connected. So far I have only found this solution to work.